# Desenvolvimento em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Foi pedido para criar uma função que altere o paragrafo para negrito, quando o mouse estiver posicionado sobre o mesmo. No entanto, não estou conseguindo resolver. Se alguém puder me ajudar, abaixo parte do código feito.

```
function changeTipo(){
    document.getElementById('paragra').style.font-weight.bold;
}

<p id = "paragra" onMouseOver = "changeTipo()">Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto TextoTexto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto.</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sua sintaxe para setar a propriedade está incorreta, o certo é: `fontWeight = 'bold'`

Aproveitei e também adicionei o tipo, assim caso for 'over' você seta pra bold a propriedade se não for ele reseta pra normal.

```js
function changeTipo(tipo) {
  document.getElementById('paragra').style.fontWeight = tipo == 'over' ? 'bold' : 'normal';
}
```

```html
<p id="paragra" onMouseOver="changeTipo('over')" onMouseOut="changeTipo('')">Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto TextoTexto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto.</p>
```